# Why does the compiler in NextJS stop working?

Tags: next.js, compilation

I have created an app with NextJS and everything was working fine and suddenly it stopped compiling in the browser.

I deleted the node module and reinstalled again and it didn't work. I updated NextJS and changed ports without good results.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aAcC.png)

Here is my terminal:

```
> second-next-app@ dev C:\Users\Rafaelventura\Google Drive\Diseno\Web\Next_JS\second-next-app
> next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\Rafaelventura\Google Drive\Diseno\Web\Next_JS\second-next-app\.env.local
```

As you can see there is no

```
event - compiling successfully ...
```

What can I do to make it compile again?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your project's `.next/cache` directory?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you're using Windows. In your terminal, go to your project's root directory (`second-next-app`) and type the following command: `del ".next\cache"`. Then answer the confirmation prompt (`y`) before re-running `npm run dev`.

Comment: No, I haven't tried. Could you tell me how to do it properly?

Comment: I get this in the terminal
You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this operation.
Online: 1 Character: 1

Comment: + del ".next\cache"
+ CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: (client-evelopment:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-It  
   em], IOException

Comment: Try this command instead: `Remove-Item .\.next\cache -Force -Recurse`

Comment: The command to clear the cache worked but I still have the same problem on the compiling

Comment: Maybe it's getting stuck on something when loading the `.env.local` file? Is there a way to temporarily skip that file just to see if it can compile without it? If it compiles without `.env.local`, then it could mean your problem is somewhere in that file.

Comment: The app is not using .env.local at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error was that my project was hosted in my Google Drive folder (in the cloud). I put my project in a local file on my PC (Not in the cloud) and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).